# VUE - Generar componentes dinamicos

Tags: vue.js

Tengo una lista json el cual contiene un campo especial: `tipo` este se encarga de saber que componente debe mostrarse, hay varios tipo aclarando.

```
{
 id: 1,
 nombre: Listado de tareas,
 tipo: BlockComponent
},
 id: 1,
 nombre: Listado de tareas,
 tipo: LineComponent
},
```

esta información la estoy obteniendo mediante `axios`. Mi problema es, como puedo saber que componente renderizar, debido a que pueden ser varios de mismo tipo o incluso ninguno. Con Laravel los estaba realizando muy fácil debido a que es php y era similar a esto:

```
@foreach($bloques as $bloque)
     @include('components.'. $bloque['tipo'], [
     'info' => $info])
 @endforeach
```

Pero con vue como podria realizarlo de tal manera que sepa que componente mostrar.

Estaba pensando en algo similar a esto:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(item, index) in bloques" :key="index">
    <{{item.tipo}}></{{item.tipo}}>
</div>
```

Pero claro esta que no los renderiza.

Comment: Te estaba por poner una respuesta similar a eso ultimo que pusiste.. pero adentro iba a agregar un v-if por componente?

Comment: de echo no lo renderiza de esa forma.

Comment: no no.. por eso.. yo pondria un <div v-if=item.tipo = 'componente'> (a groso modo) y adentro de cada div, como se renderiza el componente... de esa forma manejas cada uno por separado...